# Extended app not showing in central admin

Tags: central-administration, bug, intranet, internet

I currently have an SP2010 internet website with claims. It's working well and I'd like to extend it to an intranet. So I extended my existing webapp and disabled anonymous access. the thing is, even though the app is created and running in IIS, it's not showing in the application management interface.

I can't create any site collection for this newly created app either (not showing). However I can delete the site from sharepoint with the "delete a website from IIS" option. I also tried iisreset without much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 Central Administration only separate web applications are listed under Application Management. If you extend an existing web application to a new IIS site, it will not be listed there as it is the same web application, just the different zone. And it provides the SAME content (same site collections), but it could have different url and authentication mechanism. You can see different zones if you mark web application on the Application Management page and click on the Authentication providers button in the ribbon. Check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261698%28v=office.14%29.aspx) page for more information on Web application extending.

If you need to create a different site collection for your intranet users, you should not extend web application, but create a new one instead.

Comment: Thanks this clears things up. Only thing that bothers me with different webapp is list sharing. I plan on doing list on the intranet site that I'm gonna expose read only on the internet site.

Comment: There are different approaches you could use to provide information from one web applicaiton/site collection to another one. It all depends on your solution architecture and requirements. In simple cases you could even create a new subsite for your intranet users on existing site collection and adjust permissions on that.

Comment: I just need to have an internet (claims auth with anon access), intranet (windows auth with AD) and extranet (FBA). I'd like to have everything in the same app but not sure how to restrict access properly. How to affect subsite to zones ?